# Could you explain spring-boot thread's classloader principals in servlet init() vs servlet request?

Tags: servlets, classloader, birt, spring-boot, struts1

We have a working `spring-boot` powered app using embedded Tomcat, and one of the servlets is a legacy Struts 1.3.10 one (don't ask). And this is working perfectly fine!

Or it was until we added `BIRT` viewer servlet, which `init()` code changes the thread's classloader.

To summarise in `@Confuguration` both Struts Servlet and BIRT Servlet are normal `ServletRegistrationBean`s.

[BIRT Servlet](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.eclipse.birt.runtime/viewservlets/4.3.1/org/eclipse/birt/report/servlet/BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.java#99) in `init()` is doing the following:

```
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(this.getClass().getClassLoader());
```

Once the app is running, on each request to [Struts Servlet](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.struts/struts-core/1.3.10/org/apache/struts/chain/ComposableRequestProcessor.java#ComposableRequestProcessor), it tries to resolve the needed property from a prepopulated HashMap, where the key is the CLassLoader, and it fails to find a match:

```
ClassLoader cl = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
```

This is the outcome:

`2014-06-10 08:33:28.971 ERROR 16572 --- [nio-9087-exec-4] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[ActionServlet] : Servlet.service() for servlet [ActionServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Cannot find catalog 'struts'] with root cause`

The way I solved it out of no other ideas, is to revert the classloader just before init() is done, by extending BIRT servlet:

```
public class BirtEngineServletWorkaround extends BirtEngineServlet {

@Override
public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {

    ClassLoader savedClassLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();

    super.init(config);

    //return classloader to this thread o_O!
    Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(savedClassLoader);
}
}
```

**QUESTION:** Why changing the thread's classloader is allowed? Is this setting or getting the classloader in this particular case wrong? Would classloaders be fine if it wasn't in embedded container? Should thread's classloader be mutable? Could somebody be so kind and lecture me a bit about this?